# How to change class of first element in Javascript array with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, css

I want to create simple product slider with thumbnails. Although there may be more than 3 thumbnails, I want to show only 3 of them. By clicking 'more' button i am aiming to hide first image which is already visible and show one from hidden images by changing their class.

Code works fine untill hiddenImages[0]. Firefox console gives the following error: "TypeError: hiddenImages[0] is undefined"

What i am doing wrong?

```js
// All images
var images = $('[data-image]');

// Click for more images
var more = $('.more');


// Add show class to all images
images.each(function(index, element){$(this).parent().addClass('visible')})

// Hide images begining from 4th image
images.each(function(index, element){if($(this).data('image') >= 4)
{$(this).parent().removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden')} })

// Show big image when clicking thumbnail
images.each( function(index, element){
$(this).click(function(){ $('#pic img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src')) }) })


// Hide 1st from visible images and show first from hidden images
more.on('click', function(){
// Find all hidden images and remove visible class from first one
hiddenImages = images.hasClass('hidden');
hiddenImages[0].removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
})
```

```css
#pic {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid  #ccc;
  margin-right: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.thumbnails {
  height: 300px;
  width: 50px;
  padding:0; 
  margin:0;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;

}

.thumbnails li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}

.thumbnails li img {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.more {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}

.hidden {display: none!important;} 

.visible {display: block!important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="holder">
 <div id="pic">
 <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/nature">
 </div>

 <ul class="thumbnails">
  <li><img data-image="1" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/nature"></li>
  <li><img data-image="2" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/any"></li>
  <li><img data-image="3" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/animals"></li>
  <li><img data-image="4" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/sepia"></li>
  <li><img data-image="5" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/grayscale"></li>
  <li><img data-image="6" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/tech"></li>
  <li class="more">MORE</li>
 </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Try using [`.get(0)`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) instead of `[0]` if you want the actual DOM element. If you still want the jQuery wrapped element, use [`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/)

Comment: get(0) gives another error " TypeError: hiddenImages.get is not a function"

Comment: Ohhh, yeah that's because `.hasClass()` returns a boolean.

Comment: Seems like you should simplify your overall strategy. Since the thumbnails seem to be a fixed size, why not just have a fixed size container that allows only 3 to be visible and hides the overflow. Then it's just a matter of adjusting the position of the container's content.

Comment: TypeError: hiddenImages.first is not a function

Comment: @jeyhun_mikayil have a look at the example i have posted and accept the answer if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 2):

`images.hasClass('hidden')` doesn't do what you think it does. Check out [the `hasClass()` docs](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/). It returns a boolean.

Assuming that you're trying to get an array of objects with that class, you want to use `find()`

You're also going to want to confirm that the result of  `images.find('.hidden')` returns an array of expected length (not demonstrated below).

```
more.on('click', function(){
    // Find all hidden images and remove visible class from first one
    hiddenImages = images.filter("[class~='hidden']");
    hiddenImages[0].removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
})
```

Here's a simple example with divs to illustrate:

```js
let divsWithClass = $("div").filter("[class~='hidden']")
alert(`divs with 'hidden' class: ${divsWithClass.length}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo1"></div>
<div class="foo1"></div>
<div class="foo1"></div>
<div class="foo1"></div>
<div class="hidden"></div>
<div class="hidden"></div>
<div class="hidden"></div>
<div class="foo1"></div>
<div class="foo1"></div>
<div class="foo1"></div>
```

Comment: `images` are the actual images, `.find()` will find children

Comment: Thanks, @mhodges, I missed that. Updated.

Comment: Looking more at this, it's actually the `.parent()` of the images that has the `visible` and `hidden` classes.

Comment: Hmm. If the OP can't get there using my example above, they can't get there :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. using " .eq(0) " instead of [0] , get(0) and first() solved my issue.

Comment: @jeyhun_mikayil, Did I answer your question? If so, please click the check mark beside my answer. Also, As Alexander put in a fair amount of work below to get you pointed in the right direction, it would also be appropriate to vote up his answer as a thank you. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @yehun_mikayil - if this answered your question, please DO click the checkmark to "accept" the answer.  (That's the way SO works, and it's why people are willing to help!)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out already in an answer above the problem is `hasClass()` returns a Boolean and not a jQuery set of elements, subsequently even if hasClass() did return say a set of jQuery elements your next line of code would fail as it does because `hiddenImages[0]` is not a jQuery object. below is an example of how you could have 3 active images and interchange the classes:

```js
$(function() {
  
    // All images
    var images = $('[data-image]'),
      // Click for more images
      more = $('.more');
  
    // Add show class to all images
    images.each(function(index, element) {
      $(this).parent().addClass('visible')
    })
  
    // Hide images begining from 4th image
    images.each(function(index, element) {
      if ($(this).data('image') >= 4) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden')
      }
    })
  
    // Show big image when clicking thumbnail
    images.each(function(index, element) {
      $(this).click(function() {
        $('#pic img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'))
      })
    })
  
  
    // Hide 1st from visible images and show first from hidden images
    var hiddenElemInfoObj = {
        idx: $('.thumbnails > li.hidden').first().index(),
        initialIdx: $('.thumbnails > li.hidden').first().index(),
        lengthOfElems: $('.thumbnails > li.hidden').length - 1 // To make length zero based 
      },
      visibleElemInfoObj = {
        idx: $('.thumbnails > li.visible').first().index(),
        initialIdx: $('.thumbnails > li.visible').first().index(),
        lengthOfElems: $('.thumbnails > li.visible').length - 1 // To make length zero based
      }
  
  
    more.on('click', function() {
  
      $thumbnails = $('.thumbnails');
  
      if (parseInt(hiddenElemInfoObj['idx']) > (parseInt(hiddenElemInfoObj['initialIdx']) + parseInt(hiddenElemInfoObj['lengthOfElems']))) {
        hiddenElemInfoObj['idx'] = $('.thumbnails > li.hidden').first().index();
        hiddenElemInfoObj['initialIdx'] = $('.thumbnails > li.hidden').first().index();
      }
  
      if (parseInt(visibleElemInfoObj['idx']) > (parseInt(visibleElemInfoObj['initialIdx']) + parseInt(visibleElemInfoObj['lengthOfElems']))) {
        visibleElemInfoObj['idx'] = $('.thumbnails > li.visible').first().index();
        visibleElemInfoObj['initialIdx'] = $('.thumbnails > li.visible').first().index();
      }
  
      $thumbnails
        .children('li')
        .eq(hiddenElemInfoObj.idx)
        .removeClass('hidden')
        .addClass('visible');
  
      $thumbnails
        .children('li')
        .eq(visibleElemInfoObj.idx)
        .removeClass('visible')
        .addClass('hidden');
  
      hiddenElemInfoObj['idx'] = parseInt(hiddenElemInfoObj['idx']) + 1;
      visibleElemInfoObj['idx'] = parseInt(visibleElemInfoObj['idx']) + 1;
  
    });
  
  
  });
```

```css
#pic {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-right: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.thumbnails {
  height: 300px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.thumbnails li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}

.thumbnails li img {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.more {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}

.visible {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="holder">
  <div id="pic"><img src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/nature"></div>
  <ul class="thumbnails">
   <li><img data-image="1" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/nature"></li>
   <li><img data-image="2" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/any"></li>
   <li><img data-image="3" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/animals"></li>
   <li><img data-image="4" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/sepia"></li>
   <li><img data-image="5" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/grayscale"></li>
   <li><img data-image="6" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/tech"></li>
   <li class="more">MORE</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: @aleksander-solonik Your approach is much better. Thank you. But there is a minor issue. After 3rd click of "MORE" button regular changing method of thumbnails doesnt work.

Comment: @jeyhun_mikayil what do you mean by `regular changing meathod` ? can you be a bit more specific ?

Comment: in default images changes one by one, but suddenly function changes 2 or more images simultaneosly